# How to "Save as" via Button programmatically

Tags: android

In my android app, I'm producing a lot of data which I store at the moment in a .txt file simply called "`logData`". Now my boss wants me to give him the possibility to save it as  an extra file, like the `Save As` Button in various windows programms.

At the moment I have a method for generating a logFile and write first data to it and one for writing all coming data to it. But how can I implement a "Save as" functionality?

Here the code of both methods and the used variables:

```
private String logData = "logData.txt";
private String logText = "";
private File extStorageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
private File mLogFile = new File(extStorageDir, "DCULogData/logData.txt");
```

generating:

```
public void generateLogFileOnSD(String sFilename, String sBody) {
    try {
        File logFile = new File(extStorageDir, sFilename);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(logFile);
        writer.append(sBody);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

writing:

```
public void writeLogFileOnSD(String sFilename, String sBody) {

    if (mLogFile.exists()) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(mLogFile);
            OutputStreamWriter mOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
            mOutWriter.append(sBody);
            mOutWriter.close();
            fOut.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        generateLogFileOnSD(logData, logText);
    }
}
```

**EDIT : This is my solution based on Simple Plan's answer. Thanks for this!**

I also tested some scenarios with filenames like "/blabla", "m/m/m/m/m/". No failure found until now :)

```
public Button.OnClickListener saveLogFileOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                DiagnosisActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.save_file_dialog);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        final EditText input = new EditText(
                                DiagnosisActivity.this);
                        input.setSingleLine();
                        AlertDialog.Builder ad = new Builder(
                                DiagnosisActivity.this);
                        ad.setTitle("Enter save as File Name");
                        ad.setView(input);
                        ad.setCancelable(true);
                        ad.setPositiveButton("Save as",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(
                                            DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                                        int len = input.length();
                                        if (len != 0) {
                                            final_filename = input
                                                    .getText().toString()
                                                    .trim();

                                            generateLogFileOnSD(
                                                    "DCULogData/"
                                                            + final_filename
                                                            + ".txt",
                                                    ReceiverThread
                                                            .getLogText());
                                            Toast.makeText(
                                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                                    "Saved!",
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                                    .show();
                                        } else {
                                            Toast.makeText(
                                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                                    "Enter a proper name",
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                                    .show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                        ad.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                    public void onClick(
                                            DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });

                        AlertDialog alert = ad.create();
                        alert.show();
                    }
                });
        builder.setNegativeButton("No",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();

                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert1 = builder.create();
        alert1.show();
    }
};
```

Comment: Save as possibilities? give me name of another formats which you want to used in save as

Comment: I want a button and when I click it, it opens a little dialog where I can enter a filename and when I press ok it saves my data into a txt file with the given name ...

Comment: Oh ... I just got a clue about what I could try :) thx to your question @Simple Plan

Comment: try as per my answer:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add `Button` into your Layout as a text `Save as` and implement `OnClickListner()`

```
String final_filename;
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                annual_crop.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

                                 AlertDialog.Builder al1 = new Builder(youractivity);
                                al1.setMessage("Do you want to save a file?");

                                al1.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                            public void onClick(
                                                    DialogInterface dialog,
                                                    int which) {

                                                final EditText input = new EditText(
                                                        youractivity.this);
                                                input.setSingleLine();

                                                AlertDialog.Builder al = new Builder(
                                                        AgriListView.this);
                                                al.setTitle("Enter save as File Name");
                                                al.setView(input);
                                                al.setCancelable(true);
                                                al.setIcon(R.drawable.bt);
                                                al.setPositiveButton(
                                                        "Save as",
                                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                                            public void onClick(
                                                                    DialogInterface dialog,
                                                                    int which) {

                                                                int len = input
                                                                        .length();

                                                                if (!(len == 0)) {


                    final_filename=input.getText().toString.trim();
                                                                                    );



                                                                } else {

                                                                    Toast.makeText(
                                                                            getApplicationContext(),
                                                                            "Enter Name Properly",
                                                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                                                            .show();
                                                                }
                                                            }

                                                        });

                                                al.setNegativeButton(
                                                        "Cancel",
                                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                                            public void onClick(
                                                                    DialogInterface dialog,
                                                                    int which) {
                                                                dialog.cancel();
                                                            }
                                                        });

                                                AlertDialog alert = al.create();
                                                alert.show();
                                            }
                                        });

                                al1.setNegativeButton("No",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                            public void onClick(
                                                    DialogInterface dialog,
                                                    int which) {
                                                dialog.cancel();

                                            }
                                        });

                                AlertDialog alert1 = al1.create();
                                alert1.show();
                            }

                        });


                            }

                        });
```

And used `final_filename` like below:

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "DCULogData");
File mLogFile = new File(folder.getPath(), final_filename);
```

And add `permission` in your `manifest.xml` file

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I'm testing it at the moment :) but sounds like a good solution, altough its a bit weird to read here in SO on my 14 inch display :)

Comment: @Fraggles if u have doubts then let me know.ok

Comment: should I post my exact answer here too? Just to show what is the code of solution ?